# drush user-block feature and 'You do not have permission to block'

Tags: drush, 6

I'm trying to use [drush's user-block](http://drush.ws/#user-block) feature and I'm getting following error:

```
# drush -r . -l fqdn ublk 'user.email@host.tld.dev'
You do not have permission to block user.email@host.tld.dev.           [error]
#
```

I'm doing it from shell and I am *root*, so I'm not sure which permissions is it talking about.

Comment: Did you cd to the document root?

Comment: @heshanlk Yes I did, if I wouldn't be in root of Drupal, I'd get another message: "The directory /tmp/ does not contain a valid Drupal installation"

Comment: did you just try with uid? I think if you are using email you need to set an option. You can try `drush -d ublk --email=user.email@host.tld.dev`

Comment: @heshanlk yes, I've tried it like that as well, although it's `--mail` not `--email` and then I get another error messaging saying `Missing required argument: 'users'.  See `drush help user-block` for      [error]`

Comment: What do you get when you try with -d?

Comment: @heshanlk, same thing `Missing required argument: 'users'.  See `drush help user-block` for      [error]`

Comment: Are you sure the user exits on your system?. Try with uid?. `drush user-block 5,user3 --uid=2,3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes modules does not respect that user with UID 1 should be allowed to do everything. *And sometimes you simply want hooks to fire with specific user's ID.*

When it happens, you can use `drush --user=123` where 123 is UID of an user that is allowed to perform given action.

Source: [Drush issue 1126240](https://drupal.org/node/1126240).

Comment: I'm getting error doing that as well, `Missing required argument: 'users'.  See `drush help user-block` for      [error]`

Comment: @alexus that's an unrelated error. It means you are trying to block users but don't tell Drupal which users to block.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm following your "answer" to my "question", if I use your command this is the error that I get.

Comment: @alexus I didn't give you full command, just an option to add. Show your full command and we will be able to see what's wrong. Seems like something got between block command and it's user list

Comment: I was able to get it going by doing my command + yours : `drush -r . -l fqdn ublk 'XXX@XXX.XXX' --user=XXX`, the problem with this, is that I have to know _ALL_ userid & email in order to block user. I have few hundreds of users to block, so it's ...... seems like `drush` should be able to do it w/out specifying both.

Comment: @alexus `--user=constant_uid_of_admin` should very well be enough. You shouldn't need to use blocked user's UID to do that... if you do, you should fill support request on drush issue queue, something strange is happening.

Comment: fyi, if i specify `drush ublk XXX@XXX.TPL --user=ANYTHING`, it will go through and user will be disabled and what I specify in `--user` is really irrelevant to actual user that I was trying to disable..

Comment: @alexus In that case one of your modules detects lack of User ID, thinks it is an anonymous access and shuts it down. Bug? In that module, not Drush, if anything. Worth debugging? Don't really think so.